# style="cursor: pointer" for Font tag is working in Chrome but not in IE or Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The trimmed html is as below. When I open it in chrome, I can see the hand cursor but not in IE or Edge. I saved this html on desktop and then opened in different browsers - Chrome, IE and Edge. Except in chrome it is not showing the hand cursor for the elements with style="cursor: pointer".

What is going wrong here?

```
            <html>
                <body>
                        <DIV id=divSmart>
                            <SPAN></SPAN>
                            <DIV id=info contentEditable=true align=left colspan="2">
                                <TABLE id=airTable style="FONT-SIZE: 11pt; FONT-FAMILY: Consolas; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse; BORDER-SPACING: 0" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 width="98%" border=0>
                                    <TBODY>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=6>NEUTRAL*</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=6 noWrap>DEN ALTERNATE APA BJC/LAX ALTERNATE BUR LGB ONT SNA</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD noWrap>1</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="Star Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*A</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="United Airlines Inc" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>UA</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">744</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=F91 title="Click To Sell F-First Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>F9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=C91 title="Click To Sell C-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=A91 title="Click To Sell A-First Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>A9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D91 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Z91 title="Click To Sell Z-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Z9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=P91 title="Click To Sell P-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>P9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y91 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B91 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B9</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp; 200P 328P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Arrives 90-100% within 15 minutes of scheduled time." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>9</FONT></TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Boeing 737-900" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 739</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD noWrap>2</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="Star Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*A</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Air New Zealand" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>NZ</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">9491</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=C42 title="Click To Sell C-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D42 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Z42 title="Click To Sell Z-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Z4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=J42 title="Click To Sell J-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>J4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y42 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B42 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=M42 title="Click To Sell M-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>M4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=H42 title="Click To Sell H-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>H4</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp; 200P 328P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>* </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Boeing 737-900" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 739</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=6 noWrap>NZ9491 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD noWrap>3</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="Star Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff></FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Direct Sell Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>$</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Fiji Airways" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>FJ</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">5104</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=J43 title="Click To Sell J-Business" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>J4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D43 title="Click To Sell D-Business" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=C43 title="Click To Sell C-Business" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Z43 title="Click To Sell Z-Business" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Z4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y43 title="Click To Sell Y-Economy/Coach" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B43 title="Click To Sell B-Economy/Coach" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=H43 title="Click To Sell H-Economy/Coach" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>H4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=L43 title="Click To Sell L-Economy/Coach" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>L4</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp; 225P 403P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>* </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Airbus A319" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 319</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=6 noWrap>FJ5104 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD noWrap>4</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="One World Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*O</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Qantas Airways" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>QF</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">3057</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=J94 title="Click To Sell J-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>J9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=C94 title="Click To Sell C-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D94 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=I94 title="Click To Sell I-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>I9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y94 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B94 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=H94 title="Click To Sell H-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>H9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=K94 title="Click To Sell K-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>K9</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp; 225P 403P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>* </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Airbus A319" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 319</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=6 noWrap>QF3057 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD noWrap>5</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="One World Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*O</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="American Airlines" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>AA</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">1638</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=J75 title="Click To Sell J-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>J7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D75 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=I65 title="Click To Sell I-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>I6</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y75 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B75 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=H75 title="Click To Sell H-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>H7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=K75 title="Click To Sell K-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>K7</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=M75 title="Click To Sell M-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>M7</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp; 225P 403P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Arrives 80-89.9% within 15 minutes of scheduled time." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>8</FONT></TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Airbus A319" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 319</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD noWrap>6</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="Star Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*A</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="United Airlines Inc" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>UA</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">1216</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=F96 title="Click To Sell F-First Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>F9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=C96 title="Click To Sell C-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=A96 title="Click To Sell A-First Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>A9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D96 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Z96 title="Click To Sell Z-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Z9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=P96 title="Click To Sell P-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>P9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y96 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y9</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B96 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B9</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;1250P 214P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Arrives 80-89.9% within 15 minutes of scheduled time." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>8</FONT></TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Boeing 737-900" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 739</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor1>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD noWrap>7</TD>
                                            <TD><FONT title="Star Alliance" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>*A</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Seamless Availability" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>#</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT title="Air New Zealand" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>NZ</FONT>&nbsp;<A title="Flight Information.">9493</A>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><FONT id=C47 title="Click To Sell C-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>C4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=D47 title="Click To Sell D-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>D4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Z47 title="Click To Sell Z-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Z4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=J47 title="Click To Sell J-Business Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>J4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=Y47 title="Click To Sell Y-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>Y4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=B47 title="Click To Sell B-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>B4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=M47 title="Click To Sell M-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>M4</FONT>&nbsp;<FONT id=H47 title="Click To Sell H-Coach Class" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#78be20>H4</FONT>&nbsp; </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">&nbsp;<FONT title="Denver Intl Arpt, Denver, CO, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>DEN</FONT><FONT title="Los Angeles Intl Arpt, Los Angeles, CA, US" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>LAX</FONT><FONT title="Additional class of services available." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>-</FONT>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;1250P 214P </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>* </TD>
                                            <TD noWrap>&nbsp;<FONT title="Boeing 737-900" style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff> 739</FONT>&nbsp;&nbsp;0E</TD>
                                            <TD noWrap><IMG onmouseup="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" onmouseover="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_hover.png')" onmousedown="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16_select.png')" onmouseout="Javascript:ChgBtn(this,'../ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png')" title="View seatmap" class=DefaultIcon border=0 src="http://test.wspan.com/Scripts/us/GNG/ImagesGNG/Icon_Seats_Blue_16x16.png">&nbsp;</TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR class=AlternetColor2>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=7><FONT title="Brand information may be available. Click to view." style="CURSOR: pointer" color=#009eff>&lt;&lt;B&gt;&gt;</FONT></TD>
                                        </TR>
                                        <TR>
                                            <TD colSpan=3>&nbsp;</TD>
                                            <TD colSpan=6 noWrap>NZ9493 INTL ONL CNX/STP TFC </TD>
                                        </TR>
                                    </TBODY>
                                </TABLE>
                            </DIV>
                        </DIV>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Mostly the font tags are having that cursor style.

Comment: I think this is a bug with IE and Edge - remove `contentEditable="true"` from `#info` and cursor should work. Check [this issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3419602/)

Comment: Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Open your desktop link to your local file copy in IE11. Press f11 to display the dev tool.. the console will now list markup, security and xss errors. correct as required. Use the Emulation tab and the Debug tab of the dev tool to further debug you local file that is using the file:// protocol.

Comment: I removed contentEditable="true" and the problem is gone. Thanks [fen1x](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8036431/fen1x) for the information.